# Scala and Akka HTTP: Request inside a request & issue with threads

Tags: scala, httprequest, httpresponse, akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to learning Scala, Akka Streams and Akka HTTP, so apologies beforehand if the question is too basic.

I want to do an HTTP request inside an HTTP request, just like in the following piece of code:

```
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer
  import system.dispatcher

  val requestHandler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = Flow[HttpRequest].map {
    case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/api"), _, _, _) =>
      val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://www.google.com"))
      responseFuture.onComplete {
        case Success(response) =>
          response.discardEntityBytes()
          println(s"The request was successful")
        case Failure(ex) =>
          println(s"The request failed with: $ex")
      }
      //Await.result(responseFuture, 10 seconds)
      println("Reached HttpResponse")
      HttpResponse(
        StatusCodes.OK
      )
  }

  Http().bindAndHandle(requestHandler, "localhost", 8080)
```

But in the above case the result looks like this, meaning that `Reached HttpResponse` is reached first before completing the request:

```
Reached HttpResponse
The request was successful
```

I tried using `Await.result(responseFuture, 10 seconds)` (currently commented out) but it made no difference.

What am I missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a function that takes request and produces a response:

```
HttpRequest => HttpResponse
```

The challenge is that response is a type of `Future`. Therefore, you need a function that deals with it. The function that takes HttpRequest and returns Future of HttpResponse.

```
HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse]
```

And voila, [mapAsync](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html) is exactly what you need:

```
val requestHandler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _] = Flow[HttpRequest].mapAsync(2) {
  case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/api"), _, _, _) =>
    Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://www.google.com")).map (resp => {
      resp.discardEntityBytes()
      println(s"The request was successful")
      HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK)
    })
}
```

Comment: It's not really that important, but the original code returns a fresh `HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK)` rather than the result of the HTTP request.